# I have to create both iterative and recursive functions for a given recurrence

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class q2Recursion
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(q2Iterative(num));
        System.out.println(q2Recursive(num));
    }

    public static int q2Iterative(int num)
    {
        int base = 2;
        int current = base;
        int running = current;

        for(int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
        {
            running = 4 * current - 3 * num;
            current = running;
        }
        return running;
    }

    public static int q2Recursive(int num)
    {
        if(num == 1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 4 * q2Recursive(num - 1) - 3 * num;
        }
    }       
}
```

The iterative part is where it is wrong. When I input 5 I get -79 for the recursive one, and a different number for the iterative method.  The recursive relationship is:

- a<sub>1</sub> = 2 when n=1 (so that is our base case);
- a<sub>n</sub> = 4a<sub>n-1</sub> - 3n when n ≥ 2.

I dont know if I am putting it in correctly. I need some suggestions please.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish... just giving numbers without description of the task doesn't make sense.

Comment: it is meant to sub into the maths function and produce an ansewr @OusmaneDiaw num is my input

Comment: We have no clue of what you're trying to do, try to give a clear and concise detail of your purpose.

Comment: put a value into a given function and return the value both recursivlesy and iteratively is that clear enough for u @freedev

Comment: @basilroy What is the definition of the math function? Square root? Power? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: i said it read below the code omggg i clearly say the maths function is....@RealSkeptic

Comment: *a1=2 when n=1 and a=4an-1 -3n when=>2* is *not* a clear function definition. What is a1? Whan is an? Whan is a?

Comment: an is a nth term this was in the question i saw @RealSkeptic

Comment: Perhaps you mean that you saw it as `a₁ = 2; aₙ = 4aₙ₋₁ -3n`, which would have been a little clearer?

Comment: yes exactly that i dint know how to make it like that ,do u knw where iam goin wrong with that @RealSkeptic

Comment: @RealSkeptic iam going wrong in the iterative method when putting in the maths funcion

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class q2Recursion
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       int num = scan.nextInt();

       System.out.println(q2Iterative(num));
       System.out.println(q2Recursive(num));
   }
    public static int q2Iterative(int num)
    {
        int base = 2;
        int current = base;
        int running = current;

        for(int i=2;i<=num;i++)
        {
            running = (4*(current)) - (3*(i));
            current = running;
        }
        return running;
    }
    public static int q2Recursive(int num)
    {
        if(num == 1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 4*(q2Recursive(num-1))-3*(num);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update of running, you want to use the equivalent of the recursive function's current value of `num`.  That's `i` in your iteration.  Also, you can just initialize `running` to 2 and re-use it in the loop. That allows you to drop `current` and `base` entirely:

```
running = 4 * running - 3 * i;
```

Comment: i got it and i posted my ansewr below its fine now

Comment: @basilroy Note that your answer creates unnecessary variables and does additional work to maintain them.  You don't need `base` or `current`, you just need to initialize `running` to 2.